# How to extend a sf lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I want a combobox populated with some data from salesforce, so I am extending class with LightningCombobox:

```
export default class LwcSellerSettings extends LightningCombobox {

    fields = ["Id", "Name", "Default__c", "Ml_User__r.ML_Id__c", "Ml_User__r.Site_Id__r.ML_ID__c", "Ml_User__r.Site_Id__r.Default_Currency_Id__r.ML_ID__c"];

    renderedCallback() {
        if (!this.initialized) this.initialize();
    }

    async initialize() {
        this.initialized = true;

        let records = await query({table: 'Seller_Setting__c', fields: this.fields});

        this.options = records.map(d => ({value: d.Id, label: d.Name, key: d.Id, data: d}));
        this.value = this.options.filter(d => d.data.Default__c).concat(this.options)[0].value;
    }
```

Problem is I don't know how to make the template be the same as the one lightning combobox uses.

I tried using `import template from 'lightning/combobox.html';` to return that in render function but it didn't work, doesn't seem to be the right path.

How to inherit the template from LightningCombobox?

Comment: Might be easier to just build your own based on the source code they just published:
https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/combobox

Comment: you can populate lightning combobox options with your own data. I am not sure why you want to extend combobox just to put some data in it?

Comment: @salesforce-sas I will use that combobox with that same data a lot of times, and it has additional methods I'm not showing.

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC that might work, had searched for the html on the lwc repo and didn't find it, guess I was looking at the wrong place ^^

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer after some digging around the code:

```
import {api, getComponentDef} from 'lwc';

export default class LwcSellerSettings extends LightningCombobox {

    render() {
        return getComponentDef(LightningCombobox).template
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, did you get this to work @juvian?

Comment: @pchittum this works in lwc, it just doesn't work in salesforce